# Jqwidgets: Issues with text positioning in jqxgrid

Tags: html, css, jqxgrid, jqwidget

[image: Jqxgrid Header]

In the above picture some of the text in the header is hidden. I tried the `padding-bottom` property but that didnt help. I use the `jqxgrid` widget from `jqwidgets`

The concerned div is `.jqx-grid-header`
How should I go about to position the text upper? 
Any feedback would be helpful

Comment: Try `margin-bottom` instead, and perhaps set a max row height. Post a fiddle or sample code to help you more in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you added BR tags in your Column Header's Texts. Adding HTML Tags there will require you to implement the column's renderer callback function, too. The result of this function should be the HTML String to be displayed in  the column's header.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting it in the column definition as follows:

```
     columns: [
          { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'firstname', width: 100 },
          { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'lastname', width: 100 },
          { text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: 180 },
          { text: 'Quantity', datafield: 'quantity', width: 80, cellsalign: 'right' },
          { text: 'Unit Price', datafield: 'price', width: 90, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' },
          { text: 'Total', datafield: 'total', minwidth: 100, resizable: false, width: 'auto', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' }
     ]
```

For more information, I recommend you to read here:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/columnsresizing.htm

I hope that helps.